# open emacs with certain number of tabs open by default

Tags: tabbar

Is there a way to have emacs open up, say, 3 tabs, upon start up ?

I am tired of all the time having to open them manually and then split window also.

I would like to automate this via setting in my init.el file.

Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [desktop-save](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) for this. Start Emacs and manually set up the window configuration that you want (e.g. call `M-x split-window-right` twice, followed by `C-x +`). Then do `M-x desktop-save` and choose some directory to store the `.emacs.desktop` file (for example "~").

Then in your init file put `(desktop-read "~")` (or the directory that you chose previously) followed by `(global-tab-line-mode)` (or `(tab-bar-mode)` if you prefer that functionality) to open Emacs with tabs and your preferred window configuration.

Comment: thanks I wlll try that. whats the difference between tab-line-mode and tab-bar-mode?

Comment: I don't use tabs myself, so I can only refer you to the documentation of [tab-bar-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tab-Bars.html) and [tab-line-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tab-Line.html). If the documentation does not clarify things, then you could consider to posting another question here on SE. A very quick look, gave me the idea that tab-bar-mode is more for 'project-wise' tabs, and global-tab-line-mode is more like traditional tabs (but I might be wrong).

Answer (score 3):

In your init file, you can add code to make the window configuration the way you want. Say, three windows, equally balanced:

```
(split-window-right)
(split-window-right)
(balance-windows)
```

Comment: In this case this would indeed be the (even) more straightforward solution (followed by the tab-...-mode line of course).