# Is there a way to save layouts for Tab Bar Mode?

Tags: tabbar, persistence

I have multiple tab workspaces open. And it would be a shame if I had to open and organise them like this every time I start emacs or restart my computer.

Is there a way to save layouts?

Comment: I guess [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/650588/how-do-i-save-and-reload-a-session-in-emacs) answers that.

Comment: This answer was before tab bar mode was created.

Comment: Maybe then [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74523/26163) could be of any help?